# Image datatype in form validation of Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The form validation shows error in Codeigniter framework whenever I try to keep an image as required field.

It tells that the image field is `required` on form submission even though the image is selected. What might be the problem?

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="insurance">Insurance:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="insurance" id="insurance" type="file" value="<?php echo set_value('insurance');?>">
</div>
```

**Controller CODE:**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("insurance", "Insurance", "required");
```

Comment: show  your relevant  code

Comment: What you tried show the code....

Comment: I have edited my question. Please do have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check image is set empty or not. Please try below solution.

```
if (empty($_FILES['insurance']['name']))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('insurance', 'File', 'required');
}
```

You have to set this validation as separate validation. Please try and let me know.

You can use jQuery validation then try as below.

```
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});
$("#myform").validate({
rules: {
    insurance: {
    required: true
  }
},
messages: {
    insurance: {
    required: 'Please select the image!'
},
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes that worked in form validation.. But when i try to do the same in jQuery form validation it shows the same error again !

Comment: $("#myForm").validate({
  rules: {      
    insurance : "required"
   },
    messages:  {
     "insurance": {
      required: "You must select a file"
     }
    }
  });






















@JYoThI

Comment: @RevathiSekar please try above code and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try it using this

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile" id="userfile" value="<?php echo set_value('userfile'); ?>">

$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile','Your Label Name','required|trim');
```

Comment: $("#myForm").validate({ rules: { insurance : "required" }, messages: { "insurance": { required: "You must select a file" } } });       @Project409

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add form enctype in your form tag

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Comment: tried that too... But when it comes to form validation through jQuery validation plugin there is that error again..